# How I can start learning vhdl?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

please suggest me a good pdf or any good source that I can start learning vhdl with it. thank you.

Comment: Pick any book, or google for VHDL tutorials

Comment: @TomCarpenter Don't pick the Quran. There's no information about FPGA in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get this book: "Circuit Design and Simulation with VHDL"

Comment: thank you, it's very good book, in first look I had, it seems easy to learn.